# PrintWriter println() does not print out UTF-8 encoding in spite of previous specification

Tags: java, utf-8

I am having a problem with printWriter writing to an allready created .txt file. Although when creating a PrintWriter object i specify that i want to use UTF-8 format, when trying to open the output file (using gedit-sudo gedit-nano) all i see is unreadable and some chinese characters ( i assume they are chinese). What is more baffling, is that when printing out the data i want to insert into the file to standard output (system.out.println) the data prints fine! Furthermore, performing the file command after filling the output file to the file name through a terminal, all the command returns is "file-name.txt: data", rather than the UTF-8 i was expecting to see! I'm including the relevant bits of code, thanks in advance for any advice.

The function i use to aggregate the data i want to print:

```
public String DumpData(){
    String dump = "\0";
    dump = dump.concat(Long.toString(MessageID)).concat(",").concat(Long.toString(userID)).concat(",").concat(UserScreenName).concat(",").concat(Float.toString(Latitude)).concat(",").concat(Float.toString(Longitude)).concat(",").concat(Location).concat(",").concat(MessageDate).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(IsFavourite)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(FollowersCount)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(FollowingsCount)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Mentions)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(URLCount)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Anger_CNT)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Disgust_CNT)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Fear_CNT)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Sadness_CNT)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Surprise_CNT)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Joy_CNT)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Exclam)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Questions)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Quotations)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(IS_RT)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Caps)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Smalls)).concat(",").concat(Integer.toString(Emotion));
    return dump;
}
```

And the segment where i create the PrintWriter object and attempt to print to the file and print to standard output:

```
try {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            //out = new PrintWriter("/home/mark/Desktop/datamining/tweetfiles/annotatedTweets.csv", "UTF-8");
            out = new PrintWriter("/home/mark/Desktop/datamining/tweetfiles/tweetsafterannotation.txt","UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Testingtwitter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<mydata.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(mydata.get(i).DumpData());
            out.println(mydata.get(i).DumpData());
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Testingtwitter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: Not related to your question directly, but instead of using `.String.concat()`, you should use a `StringBuilder`

Comment: @fge since i am beggining to suspect that there is a problem with the conversion of those 2 first longs to strings, i'll try it your way. thanks!

Comment: @fge your suggestion worked! thanks so much, u have no idea how long i've been troubleshooting!

Comment: Eh? You mean using a `StringBuilder` instead of `String`'s `.concat()`??

Comment: yes, i mean exactly that. i do not know exactly why it worked, but it did and that is all i am interested in for now :D